# Problemas con bootstrap collapse al aplicarse con Drupal

Tags: bootstrap, drupal

En una sección de la página que trabaja con drupal estoy implementando cuatro imágenes con disposición horizontal. Cada una de estas imágenes abre un panel colapsable justo en la siguiente división. EL problema es que cuando le doy click a una de las imágenes para abrir el panel, el mismo drupal(eso creo) lo esconde poco después de abrirse. Le vuelves a dar click y el panel vuelve a aparecer pero inmediatamente hace el efecto de cerrarse como acordeón. Les dejo el código.

```
<section id="section-categorias" class="bloquehome" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
<div class="container-12">
  <div class="align-center">
    <h2 class="section-heading animated" data-animation="bounceInUp">CURSOS Y ACTIVIDADES</h2>
    <div class="espaciocentro"><div class="plecaverdecentro"></div></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img class="ca" src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme() .'/' ?>images/espacios/cultura-digital2.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img class="ca" src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme() .'/' ?>images/espacios/innovacion-tecnologica2.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img class="ca" src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme() .'/' ?>images/espacios/inclusion-digital.png" >
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img class="ca" src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme() .'/' ?>images/espacios/robotica.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="collapse" class="collapse">
    <div class="card card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.

    </div>
</div>
```